# Get the Contents of a file in One Drive in Outlook Add in

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, onedrive

I am currently working on an add-in which will create some files in One Drive and then use the contents of the created files later in the same addin.

I was able to create files using ms graph but I am unable to read the content of the created file.

I have used the endpoint to get file content - /me/drive/items/{item-id}/content . But it gives me failure with status code 0

Is there any other ms graph request which can be used to read the contents of the file or any other way to read the file content ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking enough detail to help the community help you. What have you tried so far? What errors/results did you get back?

Comment: Hi Marc, I have added the endpoint that I tried. Can you let me know now if there is any way we can get the file content?

Comment: Without seeing the actual result (JSON body or the HTTP trace), there isn't a lot to go on. A status code without a message is really hard to parse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OneDrive SDK for C#](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp).